# Community user cannot create SBQQ__Quote__c object in a @RemoteAction

Tags: quote, remote-action, cpq, steelbrick

I'm trying to create CPQ Quote(Steelbrick) from Community user through @RemoteAction method.

It fails with error

> Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error:
>   CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, SBQQ.QuoteAfter: execution of
>   AfterInsert caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to
>   de-reference a null object Class.SBQQ.QuoteService.processTriggerAft

The class with remote action is declared as `without sharing`, so I assume it should run in system context.
But if I execute quote creation using 'execute anonymous' in dev console, it creates a cpq quote.

In debug logs I see that the following query returns zero rows:

```
SELECT OwnerId,AccountId,Pricebook2Id,SBQQ__Renewal__c,
       Account.SBQQ__ContractCoTermination__c,
       Account.SBQQ__CoTerminationEvent__c,CurrencyIsoCode,
       (SELECT Id FROM SBQQ__Quotes2__r) 
FROM Opportunity 
WHERE Id IN ('00618000004n5gaAAA')
```

but If I run it in query editor it returns me one row.
How it's possible if the code [should run in system mode](http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring14/release-notes/rn_vf_remoting_apex_mode.htm)?

The code in the `@RemoteAction` method looks like this:

```
SBQQ__Quote__c quote = new SBQQ__Quote__c(
    SBQQ__Opportunity2__c = opportunityId,
    SBQQ__Account__c = accountId,
    SBQQ__PrimaryContact__c = contactId,
    SBQQ__Status__c = 'Draft',
    SBQQ__Primary__c = true,
    SBQQ__StartDate__c = today,
    SBQQ__EndDate__c = today.addDays( 30 ),
    SBQQ__PriceBook__c = pricebookId
);

insert quote;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your user will still need to have a license to have a quote created. Changing the sharing settings doesn't change that